# MetadataExtractor why i cant print my information outside the Console

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hay Guys, i have a question and maybe someone knows the answer. Im working today with the MetadataExtractor, everything work good but there is one thing. All the information are going into the
Console and i cant get them out from there... 
Are anyone knows how i can add the information to a label? I cant even accses the information...

```
 var directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(filename);

        // print out all metadata
        foreach (var directory in directories)
            foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
                Console.WriteLine($"{directory.Name} - {tag.Name} = {tag.Description}");

        // access the date time
        var subIfdDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
        var dateTime = subIfdDirectory?.GetDateTime(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTime);
```

Comment: Where would you expect the output of `Console.WriteLine` to go? You can just as easily take the string you're constructing and do something else with it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the String should go in diffrent labels i figured now a way where the string goes into a listbox but i just need the Informations but he give me also a description...

Comment: Consoles don't have labels, you are probably looking for a different application type, like winforms, or wpf. In fact, this question is confusing. Define what you think the console is, be explicit about what technology and application type you are using

Comment: @MichaelRandall oh im sorry.. Im using WinForms.

Comment: Then how is it ending up in the console, it takes work to get a console in winforms, are you perhaps describing the IDE output window?

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it like this (**You need the MetadataExtractor package**)

```
// access the date time
            var subIfdDirectory = directories.OfType<ExifSubIfdDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
            var dateTime = subIfdDirectory?.GetDateTime(ExifDirectoryBase.TagDateTime);
            //TEST
            // print out all metadata
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var directory in directories)
            {
                foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)

                    listBox2.Items.Add($"{tag.Description}"); //Import just Information


            }
```

then i added a **timer** the timer get the information out of the **listbox**. The Timer work with a **progressbar** together to get the Informations out.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if(progressBar1.Value == 1)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 20;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Größe: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else if (progressBar1.Value == 2)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 18;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Format: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else if(progressBar1.Value == 3)
        {
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            var imageHeight = img.Height;
            var imageWidth = img.Width;
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 3;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Abmessung: " + img.Width + " x " + img.Height;
        }
        else if (progressBar1.Value == 4)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 3;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Breite: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else if(progressBar1.Value == 5)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 2;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Höhe: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else if(progressBar1.Value == 6)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = 19;
            InfoLabel.Text += "      Dateiname: " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }   
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
```

Because it's too difficult for me, get every information in a different label i just used one label and just added the text everytime.